# How to combine two functions in R?

Tags: r

I have two functions, and I want to combine both into one function. For example, I have two different functions with the same multiple arguments as follow:

```
fun1 <- function(a, b){
            print(a * b)}

fun2 <- function(a, b){
            print(a + b)}
```

What can i do by using the existing functions to combine both into one so i can have a function like this:

```
fun3 <- function(a, b){
            print(a * b)
            print(a + b)}
```

Thank you

Comment: `fun3 <- function(a, b){return(c(a * b,a + b))}`

Comment: `fun3 <- function(a, b) { fun1(a, b); fun2(a, b) }`

Comment: You should not use `print` like this. Instead have functions return values ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `fun1` and `fun2` from the question we can define `both` which sequentially runs them.  We also test it.

```
both <- function(...) {
  fun1(...)
  fun2(...)
}

# test
both(1, 2)
## [1] 2
## [1] 3
```

Or if you wanted to return their outputs:

```
both2 <- function(...) list(fun1(...), fun2(...))
```

Alternately, we can define a factory function which given two functions having the same arguments creates a function which runs them in sequence.

```
Combine <- function(FUN1, FUN2) {
  function(...) { FUN1(...); FUN2(...) }
}

# test 
mewfun <- Combine(fun1, fun2)
newfun(1, 2)
## [1] 2
## [1] 3
```

or if you wnated to return their outputs

```
Combine2 <- function(FUN1, FUN2) {
  function(...) list(FUN1(...), FUN2(...))
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the recommendations. Your combine2 function works perfectly to my specific use.